# Output sum of inputs with same class to a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of subtotal boxes which output the value of a quantity multiplied by a unit price, and I need the values of each of these to be added together and output to a span further down in a form.

I've had a go at this using previously-suggested methods, but can't get it to work. Any ideas why?

HTML:

```
<button id="addItem" href="#">Add Item</button> <!-- Trigger button -->

<td><input name="subtotal" class="sinput txt"></td> <!-- Subtotals to add -->

<span id="totalplus" class="totalsub"></span> <!-- Output total -->
```

JS:

```
$('#invoiceItemForm button#addItem').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var sum = 0;
    $('.invoicemade .sinput').each(function() {
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $('.invoicemade span#totalplus').val(sum);

});
```

Comment: NO its a unary + @KannanJ

Comment: Still vague what you are trying to achieve. Can you explain more with a full example?

Comment: Yep Tushar, I read it up now. Tx

Comment: use `parseInt()` to get the data added.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below snippet:

```js
$('button#addItem').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var sum = 0;
    $('.sinput.txt').each(function() {
    
        sum += parseInt($(this).val()); //Change the calculation acc. to your needs
    });
    $('span#totalplus').html(sum);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addItem" href="#">Add Item</button> <!-- Trigger button -->

<td><input name="subtotal" class="sinput txt"><input name="subtotal" class="sinput txt"><input name="subtotal" class="sinput txt"></td> <!-- Subtotals to add -->

<span id="totalplus" class="totalsub"></span>
```

Removed `#invoiceItemForm` because you did not give that code.

You should use `.html()` instead of `.val()` on `span` because it is not a form control

**Note** Add `#invoiceItemForm` when using this code in your program.

Comment: Yeah, the OP's code is horribly incomplete. The example also missed an element with class="invoicemade". And it tried to write the text 'sum' into the span rather than the sum. Makes you wonder which of the errors was actually the cause of their code not working.

Comment: @MrLister Yes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt` for calculation to avoid `string concat`. Other code error are in comment.

```js
$('button#addItem').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sum = 0;
    $('.sinput').each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).val()); // Remove + 
    });
    alert(sum);
    $('#totalplus').text(sum); // Remove quote 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
<tr>
<td><input name="subtotal" class="sinput txt"></td> 
<td><input name="subtotal" class="sinput txt"></td> 
</tr>
<span id="totalplus" class="totalsub"></span> 
<button id="addItem" href="#">Add Item</button>
```

Comment: Read about `unary +`!